# How to get specific contact's "+1" Play Store applications list?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-plus

I would like to get list of **"+1"** Play Store applications of **specific contacts**. Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Google just added this to the Play Store a few days ago. Open the Play Store and tap the menu in the top left and then tap People. Here you will see an overview and some recommended apps and people. If you scroll to the bottom, you will see a few g+ contacts. Tap "See more" to view a list of all the people in your g+ circles. Then tap on the person you want and all their reviews and +1s will be there.

Comment: could not find "people" item in any menus. Can you share target page's link? When I open "Recommended for you" section, recommended applications based on my contacts and my profile are shown. This is not what I'm looking for. @abqnm

Comment: I am referring to the Android app so there is no way to link to a menu in the app. It was just added a few days ago, so it may not be on all devices yet.

Comment: hmm I see; I was speaking about web ui of Play Store. By the way I could not see any option like you said. Maybe - as you said - it is not ready for all devices.

Comment: Yeah as far as I know there isn't a way on the Web version yet. And it just started rolling out about 4 days ago to the mobile version so it could take some time for everyone to get it.